# Spatie Laravel-permission encoding issue

Tags: php, laravel, encoding, laravel-blade, laravel-permission

Using Spatie Laravel-permission package i'm facing a problem when i try to pluck the permission's name containing a 'ñ' character in a blade template like so:

```
{{ $role->permissions()->pluck('name') }}
```

Accessing to the role's name (`$role->name`) gives me a correct result, however, using the pluck method it shows in unicode format.

[image]

And before that, i'm actually accessing to the permission's name like i do in the role case `$permission->name`:

[image]

In the database looks like this:

[image]